Cannot install numexpr and pandastable packages under Python interpreter 3.13
I am trying to install pandastable package in PyCharm Community Edition 2024.2.3, project's interpreter in (venv) being Python 3.13, but process ends with error :

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numexpr      ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects
(numexpr)

I was able to install seperately 3 out of 4 pandastable package's dependencies, but installation of numexpr also ends with error:

ERROR: Failed building wheel for numexpr

(see full log below).
From https://pypi.org/project/numexpr/, under Programming Language, Python :: 3.13 is not mentionned . Does that mean that I cannot intall under interpreter Python 3.03. If so, should I downgrade to 3.12 and how.
Any hint to reactivate my project would be appreciated.
UPDATE : Problem solved. Python 3.12 interpreter installed with help of How to add a Python Interpreter into PyCharm, and Cannot Setup Python SDK” Error
Detail log:

Collecting numexpr   Using cached numexpr-2.10.1.tar.gz (101 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started   Installing build
dependencies: finished with status 'done'   Getting requirements to
build wheel: started   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished
with status 'done'   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.23.0 in
c:\users\lebla\pycharmprojects\projection\venv\lib\site-packages (from
numexpr) (2.1.2) Building wheels for collected packages: numexpr
Building wheel for numexpr (pyproject.toml): started   Building wheel
for numexpr (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error' Failed to
build numexpr
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
Building wheel for numexpr (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   exit code: 1
[131 lines of output]   C:\Users\lebla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7cnjod2a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:78:
SetuptoolsWarning: install_requires overwritten in pyproject.toml
(dependencies)
corresp(dist, value, root_dir)   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying numexpr\cpuinfo.py
-> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying numexpr\expressions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
copying numexpr\necompiler.py ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying numexpr\utils.py ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying numexpr\version.py
-> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying numexpr_init_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
running egg_info   writing numexpr.egg-info\PKG-INFO   writing
dependency_links to numexpr.egg-info\dependency_links.txt   writing
requirements to numexpr.egg-info\requires.txt   writing top-level
names to numexpr.egg-info\top_level.txt   reading manifest file
'numexpr.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest template
'MANIFEST.in'   warning: no previously-included files found matching
'numexpr_config_.py'   warning: no previously-included files found
matching 'RELEASING.txt'   warning: no previously-included files found
matching 'site.cfg'   adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'   adding
license file 'AUTHORS.txt'   writing manifest file
'numexpr.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
C:\Users\lebla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7cnjod2a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:218:
_Warning: Package 'numexpr.win32' is absent from the packages configuration.   !!
      ********************************************************************************
      ############################
      # Package would be ignored #
      ############################
      Python recognizes 'numexpr.win32' as an importable package[^1],
      but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

      This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
      package, please make sure that 'numexpr.win32' is explicitly added
      to the `packages` configuration field.

      Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
      (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
      instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

      You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

      - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

      If you don't want 'numexpr.win32' to be distributed and are
      already explicitly excluding 'numexpr.win32' via
      `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
      you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
      combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

      You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

      - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


      [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
            even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
            On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
            directory, all directories are treated like packages.
      ********************************************************************************
 !!
check.warn(importable)   C:\Users\lebla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7cnjod2a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:218:

_Warning: Package 'numexpr.tests' is absent from the packages configuration.   !!
      ********************************************************************************
      ############################
      # Package would be ignored #
      ############################
      Python recognizes 'numexpr.tests' as an importable package[^1],
      but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

      This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
      package, please make sure that 'numexpr.tests' is explicitly added
      to the `packages` configuration field.

      Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
      (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
      instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

      You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

      - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

      If you don't want 'numexpr.tests' to be distributed and are
      already explicitly excluding 'numexpr.tests' via
      `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
      you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
      combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

      You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

      - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


      [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
            even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
            On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
            directory, all directories are treated like packages.
      ********************************************************************************
 !!
check.warn(importable)   copying numexpr\complex_functions.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying

numexpr\functions.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
copying numexpr\interp_body.cpp ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying
numexpr\interpreter.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
copying numexpr\interpreter.hpp ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying
numexpr\missing_posix_functions.hpp ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying numexpr\module.cpp
-> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying numexpr\module.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
copying numexpr\msvc_function_stubs.hpp ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying
numexpr\numexpr_config.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
copying numexpr\numexpr_object.cpp ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   copying
numexpr\numexpr_object.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
copying numexpr\opcodes.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr
copying numexpr\str-two-way.hpp ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr   creating
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr\win32   copying
numexpr\win32\pthread.c ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr\win32   creating
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr\tests   copying
numexpr\tests_init_.py ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr\tests   copying
numexpr\tests\test_numexpr.py ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr\tests   copying
numexpr\win32\pthread.h ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr\win32   copying
numexpr\win32\stdint.h ->
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\numexpr\win32   running build_ext
building 'numexpr.interpreter' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++
14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/   [end of
output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for numexpr ERROR:
ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml
based projects (numexpr)


Resolved the problem on my part by installing c++ build tools for Microsoft

Download from the indicated site: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Select "Desktop development with C++" and install

Now try to install numexpr:
pip install numexpr
From the MS install UI:

